# Xamarin, Android and Google Maps: I can't move the map up and down (only left and right)

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a Page I have a `ScrollView` and inside some labels and a `Google Maps` in the middle. In Android, when I try to move the map up or down, all page is moved but the map. To display the map I'm using [Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps). I created my own `custommap` to draw a route. The component is working well, I can see the map in `iOS` and `Android` and I can move the map.

I read some posts on Stackoverflow and [this post](https://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2014/11/using-mapfragment-inside-scrollview.html) but always the guys are an Activity and the project is native.

I created:

**TouchableMapFragment**

```
public class TouchableMapFragment : MapFragment
{
  public event EventHandler TouchDown;
  public event EventHandler TouchUp;

  public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                                    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    var root = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    var wrapper = new TouchableWrapper(Activity);
    wrapper.SetBackgroundColor(Resources.GetColor(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent));
    ((ViewGroup) root).AddView(wrapper,
      new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));

    wrapper.TouchUp = () =>
    {
      if (TouchUp != null)
        TouchUp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    };
    wrapper.TouchDown = () =>
    {
      if (TouchDown != null)
        TouchDown(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    };

    return root;
  }

  class TouchableWrapper : FrameLayout
  {
    public Action TouchDown;
    public Action TouchUp;

    #region ctors
    protected TouchableWrapper(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) 
      : base(javaReference, transfer) {}
    public TouchableWrapper(Context context) 
      : this(context, null) {}
    public TouchableWrapper(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) 
      : this(context, attrs, 0) {}
    public TouchableWrapper(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
      : base(context, attrs, defStyle) { }
    #endregion

    public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
      switch (e.Action)
      {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
          if (TouchDown != null)
            TouchDown();
          break;
        case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
        case MotionEventActions.Up:
          if (TouchUp != null)
            TouchUp();
          break;
      }

      return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**view.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="600dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:name="my.awesome.namespace.TouchableMapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Activity.cs**

```
public class MyActivity : Activity
{
  private GoogleMap _map;
  private HorizontalScrollView _hsv;

  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.rtc);

    _hsv = FindViewById<HorizontalScrollView>(Resource.Id.scroll);
    SetupMapIfNeeded();
  }

  private void SetupMapIfNeeded()
  {
    if (null != _map) return;

    var frag = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<TouchableMapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);
    if (frag != null)
    {
      frag.TouchUp += (sender, args) => _hsv.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
      frag.TouchDown += (sender, args) => _hsv.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

      _map = frag.Map;
      if (_map == null) return; // will probably not happen

      // do stuff to _map here, such as adding overlays etc.
    }
  }
}
```

There are a couple of errors:

- How can I fix the problem for Android to move the map properly?
- SetContentView(Resource.Layout.rtc); what is rtc?
- Resource.Id.map doesn't exists

In my case, I have a PCL solution with iOS and Android projects. In iOS everything is fine. The only problem is for Android. How can I fix this problem?

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: it is hard to tell what is "rtc", but basically Resource.Layout.xxxx the 
xxxx" is the name of the layout file, i.e. xxxx.xml  
and any component inside layout.xml can have an "id" attribute for example if we have a <button id="@+id/something" /> then the id of the button is "something" and we can get this view from code behind by calling Button btn = (Button) Resource.id.something;

Comment: Thanks @GaneshCauda I understood that. My question is related to the code I found. I can't understand how I can use it in `Xamarin.Forms`

Comment: looking at your code, the best possibility is maybe change the "rtc" with "view" or vice versa ("view.axml" with "rtc.axml"

Comment: try to change view.axml with rtc.axml

Comment: Tried. Nothing changed. I don't have an `Activity` in my project because everything is in a `PCL` project with `ViewModels` and `Views`. In this scenario, what is `MyActivity : Activity`?

Comment: can you share your project structure? where do you put all these files?

Comment: looking at the code, seems like it is for a xamarin.android project, maybe if you can share your repo we can help you a bit better

Comment: view.axml under `Resources\layout`, TouchableMapFragment and Activity.cs in the root of the Android project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156337/discussion-between-ganesh-cauda-and-enrico).

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Comment: Hey @GraceFeng-MSFT I didn't use your code up to now because I'm in a rush to finish a sprint. I'll try it very soon. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is related to the code I found. I can't understand how I can use it in Xamarin.Forms

In XF framework, we only have one `Activity`, means the default `MainAcitivty`, all views are displayed based on this `MainAcitivty`, it you want to show a custom view from client Android project in PCL, usually we use `Custom Renderer` to create a view Renderer, for your case your `view.axml` is the layout resource in client Android project, then you should implement the logic code for this view inside the renderer.

First create a subclass of `View` in PCL so it can be used like normal XF control:

```
public class ScrollViewWithMap:View
{
}
```

Then in Android client project place your view.axml under the `Resources/layout` folder and together create it's renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollViewWithMap), typeof(ScrollViewWithMapRenderer))]

namespace YOURNAMESPACE.Droid
{
    public class ScrollViewWithMapRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                var context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
                LayoutInflater minflater = context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
                var view = minflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view, this, false);
                SetNativeControl(view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can move the logic code from your `MyActivity` to this `ScrollViewWithMapRenderer` for example:

```
public class ScrollViewWithMapRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
    private GoogleMap _map;
    private HorizontalScrollView _hsv;
    private Context context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater minflater = context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
            var view = minflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.view, this, false);
            _hsv = view.FindViewById<HorizontalScrollView>(Resource.Id.scroll);
            SetNativeControl(view);

            SetupMapIfNeeded();
        }
    }

    private void SetupMapIfNeeded()
    {
        if (null != _map) return;
        var frag = ((Activity)context).FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<TouchableMapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);
        if (frag != null)
        {
            frag.TouchUp += (sender, args) => _hsv.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            frag.TouchDown += (sender, args) => _hsv.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            _map = frag.Map;
            if (_map == null) return; // will probably not happen

            // do stuff to _map here, such as adding overlays etc.
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't find a property `Map` in your `TouchableMapFragment`, I think you code in incomplete and you should be able to solve this issue. By the way, the code `TouchableMapFragment` should also be placed in android client project.

Finally we can use this `ScrollViewWithMap` in PCL for example like this:

```
<local:ScrollViewWithMap />
```

Comment: `_map = frag.Map;` doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

1. Basically Resource.Layout.xxxx the xxxx" is the name of the layout file, i.e. xxxx.xml
2. Any component inside layout.xml can have an "id" attribute for
   example if we have a

   ```
   <Button id="@+id/something"></Button>
   ```

   then the id of the button is "something" and we can get this view from code behind
   by calling

   ```
   Button btn = (Button) v.findViewById(Resource.id.something);
   ```
3. Best possible solution based on your code, maybe change the **view.axml** to **rtc.axml**